# How to deal with streaming data in PHP?

Tags: php, streaming, twitter

There is a family of methods ([birddog, shadow, and follow](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Streaming-API-Documentation#birddog))in the Twitter API that opens a (mostly) permanent connection and allows you to follow many users. I've run the sample connection code with cURL in bash, and it works nicely: when a user I specify writes a tweet, I get a stream of XML in my console.

My question is: **how can I access data with PHP that isn't returned as a direct function call, but is streamed?** This data arrives sporadically and unpredictably, and it's not something I've ever dealt with nor do I know where to begin looking for answers. Any advice and descriptions of libraries or pitfalls would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and [fgets](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)

```
<?php
$sock = fopen('http://domain.tld/path/to/file', 'r');
$data = null;
while(($data = fgets($sock)) == TRUE)
{
    echo $data;
}
fclose($sock);
```

This is by no means great (or even good) code but it ***should*** provide the functionality you need.  You will need to add error handling and data parsing among other things.

Comment: Note Stream support was added to fopen() in PHP 5.0 so you will need at least that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that your script will time out after ~30 seconds of listening for data on the stream.  Even if it doesn't, once you get a significant server load, the sheer number of open and listening connections will bring the server to it's knees.

I would suggest you take a look at an AJAX solution that makes a call to a script that just stores a Queue of messages.  I'm not sure how the Twitter API works exactly though, so I'm not sure if you can have a script run when requested to get all the tweets, or if you have to have some sort of daemon append the tweets to a Queue that PHP can read and pass back via your AJAX call.

Comment: As far as I know though, it's just one connection. Twitter sends me an XML (is it called an object?) per message; my server isn't doing any active querying, only receiving/listening.

Comment: I would suggest setting up a Daemon that just listens (maybe written in Python, it'd likely be very simple) and dumps all tweets into a MySQL database.  Your PHP scripts can then read from the database.

Answer (score 2):

There are libraries for this these days that make things much easier (and handle the tricky bits like reconnections, socket handling, TCP backoff, etc), ie:

http://code.google.com/p/phirehose/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into using AJAX.  Im not a PHP developer, but I would think that you could wire up an AJAX call to the API and update your web page.

Answer (score 0):

Phirehose is definitely the way to go:

http://code.google.com/p/phirehose/